# Mysql_data_seek for PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to move out all of my php legacy code to *PDO Statments*. All seems it works great, but I commonly use `mysql_data_seek` function in cases like this, and I'm trying to find a way for PDO, but I honestly don't find anything related with this. This is what I actually do *(without PDO)*

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * sometable");
$array = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

$name = $array['name']

// $name is returned well, but now I want to loop it, so I use mysql_data_seek to reset the query. I want just one row, not more.

mysql_data_seek($query, 0);

// now i can loop

while($arr = mysql_fetch_assoc($array)){
    echo "name: " . $arr[$arr];
}
```

So now I'm trying to do something like this:

```
$query = $conn->query("SELECT * sometable");
$array = $query->fetch();

$name = $array['name'];

// It outputs just one row, that's what I really want to, so I want to loop it now.

foreach($query->fetchAll() as $loop){
    echo $loop['name']
}

// This time I don't get anything...
```

Any suggestions? THANKS!

Comment: If you're retrieving all results anyway, why don't you just keep it in an array, and use row `[0]["name"]` then initially.

Answer (score 0):

There is no sense in fetching the same data twice.
You did it wrong with mysqli and you shouldn't repeat it with pdo.

```
$query = $conn->query("SELECT * sometable");
$array = $query->fetchAll();
foreach($array as $row){
    echo $row['name'];
}
```

Comment: @YCS, there's already an exact duplicate of this question. Why answer -_- ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Did you read the Duplicate?